# JS alter JSON value to match key

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON and I am trying to alter it to have the same key and value string:

```
var icons = {
      "123": 63103,
      "alarm-fill": 61697,
      "alarm": 61698
}
```

I'm trying the following code:

```
var newIcons = [];

for (var key in icons) {
    if (icons.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        newIcons.key = key;
    }
}

console.log(newIcons);
```

It should return the following:

```
{
  "123": "123",
  "alarm-fill": "alarm-fill",
  "alarm": "alarm"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed description? What is the issue? What is the desired output vs expected outout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newIcons = {};

for (var key in icons) {
    newIcons[key] = key;
}

console.log(newIcons);
```